# dojo first hello dojo tutorial did not work

Tags: dojo

The first hello dojo tutorial which is provided at the main site https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/hello_dojo/index.html did not work for me.

I copy pasted the code, but the 'Hello' remains as is. The em tag does not get added. Any help!

Comment: Do you have an example of your code in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the dojo.js and put the file in the same place where the hellodojo.html is. And then I changed the code of hellodojo.html as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tutorial: Hello Dojo!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>
    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="./dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct'
            ], function(dom, domConstruct) {
                var greetingNode = dom.byId('greeting');
                domConstruct.place('<em> Dojo!!~!!</em>', greetingNode);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you will see I changed the statement

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"
        data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

And then it worked as expected, since the dojo.js is now available.
I could see 'dojo.js' in chrome extension in source too.